# How to generate a spark sql truncate query without Only

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, greenplum

I am using Spark(3.0.0_preview) and reading/writing from/to GreenPlum(version 5.24). The Greenplum version 5.24 doesn't support the "truncate table **only** $table_name" command.

With Spark 3.0.0_preview and jdbcdriver(org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.2.5), the command genearted by Spark is "truncate table **only** $table_name".

```
 df.write.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://test:5432/sample")
.option("user", "sample")
.option("password", "sample")
.option("dbtable", "test.employer")
.option("truncate", true) // **Genearte truncate table only**
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.save();
```

I want to generate truncate command without ONLY option. As the only option is not supported by Greenplum V5.24

Comment: Greenplum doesn't truncate "dependent" tables.  RI isn't enforced in Greenplum either.  So, you don't need "only".

Comment: @Jon Roberts, I don't need it but Spark is creating the truncate query with the Only option. According to the source, Spark's PostgreSQL dialect can only generate TRUNCATE ONLY ... or TRUNCATE ONLY ... CASCADE

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @mazaneicha the Spark's PostgreSQL dialect can only generate TRUNCATE ONLY

To get this working for me, I am using Scala to truncate my table. Not a good fix but would work till we upgrade to GreenPlum 6 which supports TRUNCATE TABLE ONLY

```
 truncate(""test.employer", "jdbc:postgresql://test:5432/sample","sample","sample" )
 df.write.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://test:5432/sample")
 .option("user", "sample")
 .option("password", "sample")
 .option("dbtable", "test.employer")
 .mode(SaveMode.Append)
 .save();

 def truncate(tableName: String, jdbcUrl: String, username: String, password: 
 String) = {
 val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password)
 connection.setAutoCommit(true)
 val statement = connection.createStatement()
 statement.execute(s"TRUNCATE TABLE $tableName")
 }
```